# Substring search in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, complexity

I am trying to make an algorithm that will find the index of a given substring (which I have labeled `pattern`) in a given [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) (which I have labeled `text`). This method can be compared to [`String.indexOf(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)). In addition to general feedback, I'm curious what the time complexity of my method is, and would appreciate if someone can help me figure it out.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Set;

public class SubstringSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "This is a test String";
        String pattern = "is a";
        int index = search(pattern, text);
        System.out.println(index);
    }

    private static int search(String pattern, String text) {
        int patternLength = pattern.length();
        int textLength = text.length();

        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(textLength);
        List<Integer> addList = new ArrayList<>(textLength);

        for (int i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {
            set.add(0);

            for (Integer index : set) {
                if (pattern.charAt(index) == text.charAt(i)) {
                    addList.add(index + 1);
                }
            }

            set.clear();
            set.addAll(addList);

            if (set.contains(patternLength)) {
                return i - patternLength + 1;
            }
        }

        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint 1: You don't need neither `addList` nor `set`. Hint 2: the complexity is \$ \mathcal{O}(n^2) \$

Comment: @MiguelAvila I’ve done a bit of research and found the [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm). Is that what you were referring to, or is there a more trivial way to do it that still avoids using the `Set` and the `List`?

Comment: You can do it with an statistical approach. Suposse comparing a string in average time  \$O(1)\$ and worst case \$O(n)\$, how is it possible? you will compare `pattern[i] == text[i] && pattern[i + pattern.length - 1] == text[i + text.length - 1]` using a for condition `i < pattern.length / 2`. It is less probable for human words to coincide in such a way more than 3 end-to-end comparisons with *equal lenght*. This is for single mathch not substrings, still you may extend the reasoning. Respect to the complexity of this new algorithm it could be in average \$O(n)\$ and in worst case \$O(n^2)\$

Comment: The Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm stems from a time where a character code on a computer had 256 chars. Back then, it was an interesting approach. But today, as we are working with unicode (about 143000 characters), KMP is outdated. Don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice implementation, my suggestions:

- **Bug**: `text="aa aaa"` and `pattern="aaa"` returns 1 instead of 3. Whether to handle this edge case  depends on your use case, but if `text` can be any string then it should be considered.
- **Input validation**: if `pattern` is empty or null, a null pointer exception is thrown. You can fix it by adding a condition at the beginning of the method.
- **Naming**: the method name `search` is too general. Consider a more specific one, like `firstIndexOf` or similar. The variable names `set` and `addList` also can be improved.
- **Arguments order**: this is a personal opinion, but I would put the string being searched (`text`) before the string to search for (`pattern`).
- **Exception if not found**: for such a function is common to return `-1` instead of an exception when the `pattern` is not found. In doubt, document the method.
- **Testing**: this method deserves more than one test, possibly using JUnit.
- **Complexity**: the complexity seems to be \$O(textLenght*patternLength)\$. The outer for-loop iterates on `text`, while the inner for-loop won't do more than `patternLength` iterations otherwise `pattern.charAt(index)` will throw an exception. The time complexity of `String#indexOf` is [\$O(n*m)\$](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12752295/8484783) so  the main difference to your solution regarding complexity (worst case) is probably the space complexity. Anyway, it's better to focus on the correct functionality first and performance later.

As a reference this is the [native implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l1740):

```
static int indexOf(char[] source, int sourceOffset, int sourceCount,
        char[] target, int targetOffset, int targetCount,
        int fromIndex) {
    if (fromIndex >= sourceCount) {
        return (targetCount == 0 ? sourceCount : -1);
    }
    if (fromIndex < 0) {
        fromIndex = 0;
    }
    if (targetCount == 0) {
        return fromIndex;
    }

    char first = target[targetOffset];
    int max = sourceOffset + (sourceCount - targetCount);

    for (int i = sourceOffset + fromIndex; i <= max; i++) {
        /* Look for first character. */
        if (source[i] != first) {
            while (++i <= max && source[i] != first);
        }

        /* Found first character, now look at the rest of v2 */
        if (i <= max) {
            int j = i + 1;
            int end = j + targetCount - 1;
            for (int k = targetOffset + 1; j < end && source[j]
                    == target[k]; j++, k++);

            if (j == end) {
                /* Found whole string. */
                return i - sourceOffset;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```